# Localization of 'UserMessageIfWrongCodeEntered' not working

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm having problem locating the correct key for an error messages I want to localize to another language when using a custom policy.

The message is when the user has entered the wrong TOTP-code. The english text is "Wrong code entered, please try again.". From this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids it seems as I have to edit the errormessage with StringId UserMessageIfWrongCodeEntered, and I have done so in the localizedresource with Id api.selfasserted.totp.[lang] with no success.

I also tried to look for the error message in a user flow. I found the message with the same stringId, but after changing the string there as well, the error message was still displayed in english. Which made we wonder if there is some kind of bug with this particular message?

Have anyone managed to successfully localize this error message?

Tried doing this:

```
  <LocalizedResources Id="api.selfasserted.totp.sv">
    <LocalizedStrings>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorAppIconControl" StringId="title_text">Ladda ner Microsoft Authenticator med nedladdningslänkarna för iOS och Android eller använd en annan valfri autentiserings-app.</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorAppIconControl" StringId="DN">Använd någon av metoderna nedan för att fortsätta efter att du har laddat ner autentiserings-appen.</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="QrCodeScanInstruction" StringId="DisplayName">Använd någon av metoderna nedan för att fortsätta efter att du har laddat ner autentiserings-appen.</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="totpQrCodeControl" StringId="title_text">Scanna QR-koden</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="totpQrCodeControl" StringId="info_msg">Ladda ner Microsoft Authenticator eller använd en annan valfri autentiserings-app.</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="totpQrCodeControl" StringId="link_text">Kan inte scanna? Klicka här</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorInfoControl" StringId="title_text">Skriv in uppgifterna manuellt</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorInfoControl" StringId="account_name">Kontonamn:</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorInfoControl" StringId="display_prefix">Secret</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="authenticatorInfoControl" StringId="collapse_text">Har du fortfarande problem?</LocalizedString>

      <!-- Verification -->
      <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="QrCodeVerifyInstruction" StringId="DisplayName">Skriv in verifieringskoden från autentiserings-appen.</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="otpCode" StringId="DisplayName">Skriv in din kod.</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_continue">Verifiera</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfWrongCodeEntered">Koden är felaktig, försök igen.</LocalizedString>
    </LocalizedStrings>
  </LocalizedResources>
```

All other strings other than UserMessageIfWrongCodeEntered works fine.

Comment: Could you please provide the code that you tried?

Comment: @Venkatesan edited in part of my XML that isn't working

Comment: Have you tried with this code fel kod angavs försök igen as mentioned in Ms-DOC https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#azure-ad-mfa-error-messages

Comment: I tried to localize the "UserMessageIfWrongCodeEntered" using user flow too, but not able to override the message. Raised this internally to the product team to get update on this.

Comment: @Nait Thanks for your time and patience. There are some broken elements in TOTP which require fix and team is working on it. As of now, the workaround of this is using javascript to capture the DOM element change and translate it via a function.

Answer (score 0):

From user flow => a policy => Languages, and there i selected my language.
I downloaded (on the right pane) the file for 'TOTP page' and looked what setting i needed to change.
for this specific one i needed to change: UserMessageIfIncorrectOTPCodeEntered

```
<LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfIncorrectOTPCodeEntered">Wrong code entered, please try again.</LocalizedString>
```